# Exception 'Sequence contains no elements' upon awaiting observable

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.reactive

I am using the `System.Reactive.Linq` extension methods to convert an observable to a result in an async method. The code runs correctly when I have an object reference; however, when I pass null into the `OnNext` method, the resulting awaiter throws

```
System.InvalidOperationException
 HResult=0x80131509
 Message=Sequence contains no elements.
 Source=System.Reactive
 StackTrace:
  at System.Reactive.Subjects.AsyncSubject`1.GetResult() in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Subjects\AsyncSubject.cs:line 441
  at <namespace>.DataServiceTests.<GetWithInvalidIdShouldReturnNull>d__5.MoveNext() in <local test code>
```

*I am expecting the awaiter to get a null value.*  My test is as follows:

```
[Fact]
public async void GetWithInvalidIdShouldReturnNull()
{
    var testId = shortid.ShortId.Generate();
    var result = await myTestOjbect.GetById(testId);
    Assert.Null(result);
}
```

And the `GetById` method is:

```
public IObservable<object> GetById(string id)
{
    return Observable.Create((IObserver<object> observer) => {
        var item = this._repository.Get(id);  // This returns null when id is not found in collection
        observer.OnNext(item);
        observer.OnCompleted();
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
}
```

Comment: I did find that adding `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` to the end of `GetbyId(testId)` made it work as-expected, but why?

Comment: How does the observer's OnNext() handle nulls?

Comment: If that's an error state, the observable should send OnError, not OnNext. Observers are expecting to receive valid objects in OnNext.

Comment: `await myTestOjbect.GetById` should return `null` if `_repository.Get(id) returns null`. What version of Rx are you using?

Comment: @clay - a null is preferable to an exception in this particular usage. @mm8 - `System.Reactive 4.1.3`

Comment: @TimothyJannace - the observer is a `System.Reactive.Linq` extension method called `GetAwaiter()` and I have not reviewed the source for that.

Comment: @theMayer, understood...sometimes recommendations aren't consistent w/ reality ;-)  But do check the docs for [System.IObserver<T>.OnError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobserver-1.onerror?view=netframework-4.7.2). The passed parameter isn't necessarily a "thrown" exception, but may just indicate (as is consistent with your case) that data isn't available. It's "technically" the right way to inform a client of such a case if you have an opportunity to refactor.

Comment: Per your observations about the two answers leads me to ask of you're testing in a console app...which has a totally different SynchronizationContext than a GUI-type app. [Check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It's an ancient article but a very good one. Your main test could complete before the thread pool thread that completes the async task has a chance to return.

Comment: Never ever do `return Disposable.Empty` on an `Observable.Create`. There's almost always a way to return a clean disposable and avoid potential race conditions. In your code a simple `return Observable.Return(this._repository.Get(id));` seems to be sufficient.

Comment: @Enigmativity, why would they create it if it wasn’t supposed to be used? I thought about observable.return, however the documentation was unclear on how exceptions get handled.

Comment: @theMayer - They (if you mean Microsoft) created `Application.DoEvents()` and "Microsoft Bob". Not everything created is meant to be used. You can always use an `Observable.Start` inside an `Observable.Defer` if you want too. There are tons of options - all of which are vastly better than `return Disposable.Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's where your error is being thrown:
https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Subjects/AsyncSubject.cs#L441

Looks like your subject doesn't have any observers, or the observer(s) are already disposed.

Comment: Placing the “await” creates an observer and subscribes to the observable. I think it has more to do with the fact that it doesn’t accept null as a value somewhere else, and I had already somewhat reached that conclusion.

Comment: Think it could have been that the observable was disposed since i received the same error (i.e 'Sequence contains no elements') without passing around null. And the source-code suggests this as being the cause. The fix, for me, was to omit the call to OnCompleted after the ToNext call.

Answer (score -1):

Works fine for me, though I did it in Linqpad. Here's my code:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var result = await GetById("");
    if(result == null)
        Console.WriteLine("OK!");
    else
        throw new Exception("Expected Null!");

}

public IObservable<object> GetById(string id)
{
    var o = Observable.Create<object>(obs =>
    {
        obs.OnNext(null);
        obs.OnCompleted();
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });

    return o;
}
```

Comment: Are you using different version of Rx and/or .net? Nuget shows I’m on the latest.

Comment: I checked the version. 4.1.3, Rx.net.

Comment: When you run the sample code I printed, does it work?

Comment: I did try changing the line with `repository.get` to be null, and after doing that, I posted the question. So it is puzzling why it would work for you but not for me. The only difference I see here is where the location of `<object>` is, but I will give it a try